# Retain function and function parameter typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

I want to send a function and parameters to that function to another function. When doing that I want to retain all typing information and get intellisense and all the syntax checking. The end purpose is to call that function at a later stage.

At the moment I have something like this, it works, but doesn't give me type safety with the parameters:

```
functionA () {
   return this.functionB(someService.someMethod, ["one", "two", "three"]);
}

functionB<TResponse, TFunction extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<TResponse>>(
   fn: TFunction,
   params: Parameters<TFunction>): Promise<TResponse> {

   ...
}
```

I have tried with this below, which seems to fix the calling syntax, but gives other effects like loosing the result type of the function and, more importantly, gives the error `Type 'TFunction' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any[]) => Promise<TResponse>'.` in the compiler:

```
functionB<TResponse, TFunction extends Function>(
   fn: TFunction,
   params: Parameters<TFunction>): Promise<TResponse> {

   ...
}
```

Comment: A quick [test](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIB4AVARgBp4iAmeEADwxFWAGd4AKAOm9gHMWAXPCioAngG0AugEp4AXgB88AAowcAWywsQxEgoXsAUPCSoh1MsfgAHWFHWCVd9SEYwWxKgsPShqjVo6pN6GKOjYePC87FBCLBgwWKi8FABGQqjI6qkgML4qapraBJnZuUoA3lZwGMgw+P5FIJxwLDgQAG4g7KnSANyGAL6GhmB48cLySEYmKVbiAORQCxQkkj4jY6gTqVOIM1GWJovL69Kb4xjwYHsHc8dLK-Dk8AuoONYgC2dAA) in the playground seems to retain type safety, where exactly is your issue?

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the quick response! I can't see really why that works and mine doesn't... I get params as any[]. Good to know i was on track, I'll update if i find out what was the culprit

Comment: The problem seems to come from the fact that the method calling all this is also a generic. So it couldn't infer the type I guess. It looks something like 
```private functionA<TData, TResponse>(options: RequestOptions<TData>): Promise<TResponse> {
   return this.functionB(someService.someMethod, ["one", "two", "three"]);
}```

Comment: If i changed that to a local variabel and type casted that like this ```return <Promise<TResponse>>promise;``` it worked